# Regex limit full matches with specific expression

Tags: javascript, regex

My Regex matches words and only allow one space in between. Below is my [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/BudEu9/1)

```
^([a-zA-Z\u4e00-\u9fa5]+ )*[a-zA-Z\u4e00-\u9fa5]+$
```

This works fine but i want to limit the matches including space, how can i do this? For Example:

```
{2,30}
```

And this does not work

```
^(([a-zA-Z\u4e00-\u9fa5]+ )*[a-zA-Z\u4e00-\u9fa5]+$){2,30}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead assertion to check the length:

```
^(?=.{2,30}$)([a-zA-Z\u4e00-\u9fa5]+ )*[a-zA-Z\u4e00-\u9fa5]+$
  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Explore the regex in the demo below.  I removed the unicode characters to make things simpler.

### Demo